# Codeigniter - access session with some_name

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'am trying to access an index in my CI session with some_name. In CI documentation there's a point that tell CI could save some_value in some_name.

Here is the documentation:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('some_name', 'some_value');
```

So I write it like this:

```
$data = array(
  'id_member'  => 1234,
  'nama'       => 'Andrew',
  'email'      => 'andrew@gmail.com',
  'phone'      => '086767',
  'logged_in'  => TRUE
);

$this->session->set_userdata('user',$data);
```

but when I trying to access index `id_member`, it gives me an error like this:

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
```

How should i write it correctly?

here is my error code:

```
$this->user = $this->db->get_where('member', array(
   'ID' => $this->session->userdata('user')->user_id), 1)->row();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to access array element and not object, thus the error

```
$s = $this->session->userdata('user');
$id = $s['id_member'];
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Use this hope this will help you

```
$this->user = $this->db->get_where('member', array(
   'ID' => $this->session->userdata['user']['id_member']), 1)->row();
```